# Inserting a \circ inside a minted block

Tags: xetex, minted

I'm trying to insert a `\circ` inside a `minted` block of code, to emit the following: `g ∘ f`:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{haskell}
g |\circ| f
\end{minted}
```

I was trying to follow the minted documentation, and attempted to do it inside a `escapeinside`, but without much success, I get an error:

```
<inserted text>
                $
l.2 \PYG{n+nf}{g} \PYG{esc}{\circ} \PYG{n}{f}
...
```

Am I holding it wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: tested and works! marking as duplicate

Comment: @koleygr thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it didn't work, if I replace `|\circ|` with just `$\circ$`, I get: `g \$\circ\$ f` rendered. If I place it inside the `||`, I get the same error (p.s. I fixed the error indentation, it was pasted wrong before)

Comment: I just tested with: g |$\circ$| f and works fine

Comment: I tried both with latex and xelatex using my MWE. If you tried my last comment code inside your minted environment as you have give it to as and still doesn't work, then please provide a MWE because something else causes the problem. See here how: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @koleygr thank you for the answers! I'll try to come up with an MWE

Comment: Welcome! To reviewers: Please give him some time because he may be have some other problem too and he probably can change his question